# Render different action for ajax vs html request in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, render

In rails three I have the following code for my destroy action in a photos controller

```
 def destroy
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
     if @photo.destroy
       flash[:notice] = t('photo.deleted')
       respond_to do |format|
         if request.xhr?
           format.js
         else
           format.html {redirect_to photos_path}
         end
       end
     else
       flash[:alert] = t('.photo.error_deleting')
       if request.xhr?
         redirect_to(photos_url)
       else
         redirect_to(photo_path @photo)
       end
     end
   end
```

The goal is essentially to redirect to the index page if this is called from a standard link and render destroy.js if called from a remote link.
This works but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this in rails 3.  Possibly using the respond_with operator?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
respond_to :html, :js

def destroy
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  if @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = t('photo.deleted')
  else
    flash[:alert] = t('.photo.error_deleting')
  end

  respond_with(@photo)
end
```

There is a good blog post about it here:
http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/10/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-restful-rendering

Here's a quote from the post about the logic:

> **If the :html format was requested:**
>
> - If it was a GET request, invoke render (which will display the view
>     template for the current action)
> - If it was a POST request and the resource has validation errors, render
>     :new (so the user can fix their
>     errors)
> - If it was a PUT request and the resource has validation errors, render
>     :edit (so the user can fix their
>     errors)
> - Else, redirect to the resource location (i.e. user_url)
>
> **If another format was requested, (i.e. :xml or :json)**
>
> - If it was a GET request, invoke the :to_format method on the resource and
>     send that back
> - If the resource has validation errors, send back the errors in the
>     requested format with the
>     :unprocessable_entity status code
> - If it was a POST request, invoke the :to_format method on the resource and
>     send that back with the :created
>     status and the :location of the new
>     created resource
> - Else, send back the :ok response with no body

A little more on the `to_format` part from the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html#method-i-to_format):

> First we try to render a template, if
>   the template is not available, we
>   verify if the resource responds to
>   :to_format and display it.

There is also a Railscast about it:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3